# Web Crypto API cannot import openssl keys

Tags: javascript, openssl, rsa, webcrypto-api

Right now, I am testing Web Crypto API by doing simple test. So, I have user's public key (as a string) and I want to let him pass his private key (also as a string), so my app could do some encrypting/decrypting. And so, I try to import his keys int Web Crypto API by doing:

```
var textEncoder = new TextEncoder();
var alg = {
    name: "RSA-OAEP",
    hash: {name: "SHA-256"}
}
window.crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', textEncoder.encode(myPublicKey), alg, false, ['encrypt'])
```

Keys are generateded by

```
openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 4096
openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -pubout > mykey.pub
```

WCAPI throws

```
Unsupported import key format for algorithm
```

I tried other hashes in alg, but still, no success.

A help with an example would be nice.

Comment: change `'raw'` to `'spki'`; add `-outform der` to the second openssl command line. See if that works.

Comment: -outform der made my public key look... wierd when I "cat" it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some errors:

- Change `raw` to `spki` (pointed by James K Polk)
- `TextEncoder.encode()` is not suitable for binary keys. See [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder)

  > Returns a Uint8Array containing utf-8 encoded text.
- Convert the PEM key generated by OpenSSL to binary ArrayBuffer. Use `convertPemToBinary(pemKey)` from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34995761/6371459.

Comment: It helped with public key, but it failed while i was importing private key ;( I've used `spki` and `convertPemToBinary(pemKey)` and it threw a `Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.` message.

Comment: `spk`i is not suitable for private keys. Use `pkcs8`, convert the key from PEM to pkcs8, and change 'encrypt' to 'decrypt'. I will look for a link to do the conversion

Comment: OK, so I generated new pkcs8 priv and public keys and imported them with correct args and... it works! Wow! Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer very helpful but it required a fair amount of work to get a full working example.

how I create public/private key:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.private 4096  # private (secret)
openssl rsa -in itsame.secret -pubout > key.public
```

I then copy-pasted these into the respective `script` tags below.

You can test by copying the files into the same directory and then opening `file:///path/to/play.html` in your browser

play.js

```js
// Useful docs:
// * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto

function el(id) { return document.getElementById(id) }
assert = console.assert
log    = console.log

log('loading')

const crypto = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
const subtle = crypto.subtle

assert(subtle, "SubtleCrypto not available")

const RSA_OAEP = {
  name: "RSA-OAEP",
  hash: { name: "SHA-256" }
};
const RSA_PSS = {
  name: "RSA-PSS",
  hash: { name: "SHA-256" }
};
const RSA_PSS_PARAMS = {
  name: "RSA-PSS",
  saltLength: 32, // 256 bit
}

function loadPublicKey() {
  var fake = el('fake-public-key'); if(fake) {
    return fake.innerText;
  }
}

function loadPrivateKey() {
  var fake = el('fake-private-key'); if(fake) {
    return fake.innerText;
  }
}

// encode an ArrayBuffer (of ints) as a base64 String
function encodeB64(arrayBuffer) {
  var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
  var byteString = []
  for (var i=0; i<byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
    byteString.push(String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i]));
  }
  return btoa(byteString.join(''));
}

// decode a base64 String as an ArrayBuffer (of ints)
function decodeB64(b64str) {
  var byteStr = atob(b64str);
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(byteStr.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteStr.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = byteStr.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes.buffer;
}

// remove headers like "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" and join lines.
function unfmtKey(pem) {
  var lines = pem.split('\n');
  var encoded = []
  for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].indexOf('--') < 0) {
      encoded.push(lines[i].trim())
    }
  }
  return encoded.join('')
}

function fmtKey(header, key) {
  var lines = [`-----BEGIN ${header} KEY-----`]
  var i = 0; while(i < key.length) {
    lines.push(key.slice(i, i + 64))
    i = i + 64
  }
  lines.push(`-----END ${header} KEY-----`)
  return lines.join('\n')
}

// ---------------------------
// -- ENCRYPTION / DECRYPTION
async function importKey_RSA_OAEP(key, format, keyUsages) {
  var cleanKey = unfmtKey(key)
  return await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    format,
    decodeB64(cleanKey),
    RSA_OAEP,
    false,
    keyUsages);
}
async function pubEncryptKey(key) {
  return importKey_RSA_OAEP(key, "spki", ["encrypt"])
}
async function privateEncryptKey(key) {
  return importKey_RSA_OAEP(key, "pkcs8", ["decrypt"])
}

encrypt = async function(plaintext, publicKey) {
  // create a random 96-bit initialization vector (IV)
  const iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));

  // encode the text you want to encrypt
  const encodedPlaintext = new TextEncoder().encode(plaintext);

  // prepare the secret key for encryption
  const key = await pubEncryptKey(publicKey)

  // encrypt the text with the secret key
  const encodedBuffer = await subtle.encrypt({
      name: 'RSA-OAEP',
      label: iv,
  }, key, encodedPlaintext);

  // return the encrypted text "ciphertext" and the IV
  // encoded in base64
  return ({
      ciphertext: encodeB64(encodedBuffer),
      iv: encodeB64(iv),
  })
}

decrypt = async function(ciphertext, iv, privateKey) {
  // prepare the secret key
  const key = await privateEncryptKey(privateKey)
  const cleartext = await subtle.decrypt({
      name: 'RSA-OAEP',
      label: decodeB64(iv),
  }, key, decodeB64(ciphertext))

  // decode the text and return it
  return new TextDecoder().decode(cleartext);
}

// ---------------------------
// -- SIGN / VERIFY
async function importKey_RSA_PSS(key, format, keyUsages) {
  var cleanKey = unfmtKey(key)

  return await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    format,
    decodeB64(cleanKey),
    RSA_PSS,
    false,
    keyUsages);
}

// spki is public only
async function verifyingKey(key) {
  return importKey_RSA_PSS(key, "spki", ["verify"])
}
async function signingKey(key) {
  return importKey_RSA_PSS(key, "pkcs8", ["sign"])
}

sign = async function(text, privateKey) {
  const key = await signingKey(privateKey)
  const signatureBuf = await subtle.sign(
    RSA_PSS_PARAMS,
    key,
    new TextEncoder().encode(text))
  return encodeB64(signatureBuf)
}

verify = async function(text, signature, publicKey) {
  const key = await verifyingKey(publicKey)
  return await subtle.verify(
    RSA_PSS_PARAMS,
    key,
    decodeB64(signature),
    new TextEncoder().encode(text))
}

window.onload = async function() {
  // some plaintext you want to encrypt
  const text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

  // create or bring your own base64-encoded encryption key
  // const key = encodeB64(
  //   crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(32))
  // )
  var publicKey = loadPublicKey()
  var privKey   = loadPrivateKey()

  var e = await encrypt(text, publicKey)
  log('encrypted: ' + e)
  el('encrypted').innerHTML = `
  <p>iv=${e.iv}</p>
  <p>${e.ciphertext}</p>`
  var d = await decrypt(e.ciphertext, e.iv, privKey)
  el('decrypted').innerHTML = d
  log('decrypted: ' + d)

  var s = await sign(text, privKey)
  log('signature: ' + e)
  el('signature').innerHTML = s

  var v = await verify(text, s, publicKey)
  log('verified: ' + v)
  el('verified').innerHTML = v + ''
}
```

play.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>subtle playground</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">-->
</head>
<body>
<script src="play.js"></script>
<script type="data" id="fake-private-key">
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</script>
<h1>Example public key</h1>
<script type="data" id="fake-public-key">
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
</script>

<h1>Direct (fake) Tests</h1>
<h2>Encrypted</h2>
<div id='encrypted'></div>
<h2>Decrypted</h2>
<div id='decrypted'></div>
<h2>Signature</h2>
<p><span id='signature'></span></p>
<p><b>Verfied: <span id='verified'></span></b><p>
</html>
```